Matrix trace$(AB)^k$ = trace$(BA)^k$
When trying to prove for a real valued $n \times n$ matrix that

$\operatorname{trace}((AB)^k) = \operatorname{trace}((BA)^k) $

there seems to be an additional step.
The base case $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)$ is clear, however when trying to prove this via induction I seem to get stuck on the part from

$\operatorname{trace}((AB)^{k-1}) = \operatorname{trace}((BA)^{k-1}) \to  \operatorname{trace}((AB)^{k}) = \operatorname{trace}((BA)^{k})$

where one needs to show $\operatorname{trace}(AB \cdot (BA)^{k-1}) =  \operatorname{trace}((BA)^{k})$. Would appreciate any hints regarding this

It is not true that $\operatorname{Tr}(AB\cdot (BA)^{k - 1}) = \operatorname{Tr}((BA)^{k})$, for example, take $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.
Instead you need to use the cyclic property: $$\operatorname{Tr}((AB)^k) = \operatorname{Tr}(A(BA)^{k - 1}B) = \operatorname{Tr}((BA)^{k - 1}BA) = \operatorname{Tr}((BA)^{k}).$$

By the property of the trace which you mention, the traces of $ABC$ and $BCA$ are equal for any  square matrices $A,B,C$.
